# Pandas: Sorting values using two column elements

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

how to sort a data-frame using two column values, at first look at 1st column values and only if values are duplicate then look at the 2nd column values

Comment: Do post a example of data and code showing what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Use sort_values() on dataframe as:-

```
df.sort_values(by=['col1', 'col2'])
```